# Scale 5-15V to 30-50V using op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc

I have a sensor that output signal values 5-15V. I wish to translate the given signal using op amp to 30-50V. Can u help me with the values of resistors and circuit diagram which shows sensor as well. 
Is it necessary to use buffer circuit?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Read a similar [post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/162886/27943) and its answers.

Comment: What frequency spectrum is the sensor output? Why do you need such a large DC offset on the output?

Answer (score -1):

You are looking to step up the input voltage ranging from 5-15 to 30-50Volts. This calls non inverting amplifier where the you need to choose Rf and Rin resisters such that the ratio of  (Rin+Rf)/Rin  is 6. This will help acheive 30 V when the input is 5 V.

Comment: Then for an input of 15V, output will be 90V !!! Which is not what OP wants.

Comment: I agree to your point when it is 15 Volts it will be 90. This gain will help to achieve the 5 Volts to 30 volts. Is it possible for us variable resistor at the input so that it possible for us to adjust the gain. You input here will be of help to me .

Comment: @shri - An op amp cannot (directly) provide an output greater than its power supply. So please provide the manufacturer and part number of an op amp which uses a 100 volt power supply.