# How to design a high impedance buffer circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, circuit-design, buffer, high-impedance

How can I design a buffer circuit that takes an input of +/- 10V and scales it down to a 0V to 5V.

The idea is to design a circuit that is microcontroller compatible (can be read by an analog-in pin by a typical 5V microcontroller) with input signals from Eurorack modular synthesizers outputting +/- 10V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPtHeI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think I need a high impedance input but don't know what kind of transistors to use or what configuration to use them in.

Comment: You have to define load current , efficiency and voltage tolerance and maybe dynamic loads

Comment: You need to know the required bandwidth.  And it would be helpful to know the source impedance so you can get an idea of how high impedance your circuit actually needs to be.  And also how much noise you can tolerate introducing.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37095/level-shifting-a-2-5v-signal-to-0-5v 

Sorry I found the answer here for a simple starting point. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will probably work for you:

For R1 = 49.900K the ideal value of R2 would be 20.43904K  and R3 would be 89.331K approximately.

The 4.096V source could be a 0.1% tolerance series reference that can sink or source current such as [ADR3440](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADR3412_ADR3420_ADR3425_ADR3430_ADR3433_ADR3440_ADR3450.pdf). You can play with the resistor values to make them from standard values for R2/R3 as you like so long as the ratio of R1:R2:R3 is kept the same and the values are not too high or too low.

There should be a bypass capacitor on the op-amp supply and input or output protection may be required in a real circuit.

The op-amp has to be a rail-to-rail input and output type for +5V only supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuuWhH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that if you leave the input open you will get an output voltage of 3.333V.